# check condition for DOB in C

Tags: c

How can we check that the DOB, which is the user input is in correct form DD/MM/YY through C code? Also how will we restrict DOB to 6 characters only and if these two conditions are not fulfilled it should give an error statement.
Ex - if the user i/p as DOB is 25/24/23334, it should give an error like - it's not in proper format as well as the month range is exceeding.

Comment: I want help as I am not able to do it properly,,,

Comment: You should still show us what you've tried so far.  If this is homework no one wants to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)?

Comment: but should be the check condition in terms of syntax, that it should not exceed the range and should also be in proper format.

Comment: @kamakshi: Okay, so do sscanf() and then write some if statements.

Comment: In that case do I need to make a separate function for dob and then write if statements in it?? can u hint me by writing it..